# geos: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, g++, geos

I am trying to use the geos library on a Raspbery Pi 3, using Debian. I am trying to compile a program in C ++.

The same program can be compiled on other computers, this means that the source code of my program is correct.

When executing the command `geos-config --version`, version 3.7.1 is returned to me.

A while ago, a friend compiled and has been using the same code in Raspibian. However, I can't run it on Debian. My friend does not remember how he installed the geos library.

Would anyone know of anything that could help me?

```
 make

Building target using GCC compiler: sources/geometry-manager.cpp
g++ -g -c sources/geometry-manager.cpp -std=c++17 -w -c -rdynamic -W `wx-config --cxxflags --libs --gl-libs` `geos-config --cflags` -lgeos -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -lGLEW  -o builded/geometry-manager.o `pkg-config --libs geographiclib`
In file included from sources/geometry-manager.cpp:14:
sources/../include/geometry-manager.hpp:26:10: fatal error: geos.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geos.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:37: builded/geometry-manager.o] Error 1
```

`geos-config --includes` : `/usr/include`.

`geos-config --cflags` : `-I/usr/include`.

`geos-config --libs` : `-L/usr/lib/aarcg64-linux-gnu -lgeos-3.7.1` .

I installed via apt-get. However, as it didn't work, I installed it from the cloned github repository. –

**Solution:**
I uninstalled geos from my computer. Afterwards, I deleted all the folders related to geos that were still on the computer.

For some reason, the installation from the current repository did not work. So I cloned an old version of the geos.

> https://github.com/libgeos/geos.git

I ran `autogen.sh` script (which didn't work before).
And this time it compiled and installed it successfully.

Thanks

Comment: **Please [edit] your question and add all information there. Don't use comments to answer requests for information.** Please also add the following information: Did you remove the package you installed with `apt-get` before installing from a GitHub repository? Please add a link to the repo. What commands di you use to install the library from source? Does a file `/usr/include/geos.h` exist? Does `/usr/local/include/geos.h` exist? You wrote "I installed via apt-get. However, as *it didn't work*, ...". What exactly means "it didn't work"?

Comment: Good that you added the information from your comment to the question. Unfortunately you did not answer the questions from my previous comment. My guess is that you might have a `geos-config` in your path that does not match your current installation of the library's header files.